# Electron with java how to package?

Tags: java, installation, cross-platform, desktop-application

I need to build a desktop application which the GUI just to modify a configuration file and java application running as a window service (or cron job in linux) to do processing.

I was thinking to use electron as GUI and java as background.
I quite like the idea of electron where I can use html and other web frameworks compare to JavaFX.

How can I package it together as an installer?
Or any other ideas is welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made something similar using sockets.
I connect my Electron to my Java application via Socket (nodejs "`net` library).
I can communicate bidirectional and sending a Java command I can open electron Window. 
I think this can be a solution even in your case.

Comment: When you built your app did you package it with electron builder?

Answer (score 1):

Check out [InstallBuilder 16](https://installbuilder.bitrock.com/) which is, unfortunately, quite pricey (around 2000$ for combined Windows/Linux install).

If you want to go open-source, try http://izpack.org/.